# Where is MySQL database stored in Laravel Homestead on Windows local machine?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I set up Laravel framework with Homestead / VM Virtual Box local environment on my Windows PC. I am building a MySQL database for my Laravel project. As I go on I want to back it up, but I cannot find where the actual database is stored on my hard drive. Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: It's stored within the virtual machine. See http://superuser.com/questions/857177/where-is-virtualboxs-virtual-hard-disks-repository for how to find that.

Comment: Just fire up phpMyAdmin, that should be able to see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
sudo su
cd /var/lib/mysql/
```

I suggest you [use that](https://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/) to back it up with some cron

Comment: I am sorry I am a super noob and can't find it. I ssh'ed into vagrant and ran `sudo su`, which worked :D. But I can only go down this path: `/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/`. I can't find `/var/` folder

Comment: Perfect! many thanks! I will learn how to use the backup software you suggested now.